# Connect windows share drive using WNetAddConnection2 and token

Tags: windows, security, authorization, token, condor

I use WNetAddConnection2 to connect the windows share drive using user name and password, which store in our own database. Although I encrypt the password in the database, but have to decrypt in the client to conduct the real connection. My program is running under condor.

This method has the security risk to leak the password. Could I implement a token method to authorize the windows share drive? This token have to be generated by one computer, and used by other computers.

Our organization use windows domain to store user name and password. All computers are variable Windows operating systems.

Thanks for any suggestions. Please let me know if more information required.

Comment: Why do you have to provide special credentials?  Why not use the credentials of the logged on user?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I cannot use logged users, because our program is running  under condor.

Comment: What security context does the program run in?  Software that runs as local system or as network service can access network shares using the computer's domain account.

Comment: (The problem with a "token" is that even if it is possible, it doesn't really solve your problem, because anyone who stole a copy of the token would be able to access the network share.)

Comment: Yes I agree with you with token is not best solution and have a security risk.   Cannot think about another method to solve the security problem. Any ideas?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Don't know about the details condor permission. But Condor use a special strict user account to control permission in the client computers, which can not access a specific folder.